# Where to register observers when using IoC containers?

Tags: inversion-of-control, observable, ioc-container, dry

In my current application, I am using a 'selfmade' Observable class in order to implement the observer pattern. Observers (implementing an interface) can listen to certain events.

I am switching more and more of the project over to using an IoC container, but I fail to find a good place in the code to register the observers with the observable.

The ways to do this that I see are:

A) Inject the observable into the observer.
The constructor shouldn't do actual work, but even with method- or field injection this couples the observer with the observable. This is also the case if it's the other way around.

B) Create an observable factory and do it there.
In this case creating the observable depends on the implementations of several observers.

C) Create the observers by factory and do it there.
While this seems best to me concerning coupling, it turns out bad concerning DRY. In some cases the factory ends up being a copy of the fields and constructor of the observer, plus the observable and plus the one line of code for the registering.

Is there a way to handle this registering in a clean way? If not, are there compelling arguments to use a certain way over the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was discovering the difference between Resolve() and Instantiate() methods.

I was always using Resolve(). With that, I would receive an Observer in the way it has been bound to the container.

However, Instantiate() does not care about how the class is bound to the container. It creates the class the standard way, but still injects the dependencies. So this can be used inside the factory for the observer.